# How to implement "is also" (extending a method, as used in E language) in C++?

Tags: c++, extend

In my program I have 3 classes: GeneralHeader, MACHeader and IPHeader. MAC and IP headers are derived from General_Header:

```
//Headers.h

class GeneralHeader {
public:
    bool Valid;
    void PrintMe();
};

struct MACHeader: public GeneralHeader {
    int DestMAC:48;
    void PrintMe();
};

struct IPHeader: public GeneralHeader {
    int Version;
    void PrintMe();
};
```

I would like to implement the PrintMe() of GenedralHeader to print all its members and then to **extend** the PrintMe() method for MACHeader to print **also** MACHeader's members (so MACHeader.PrintMe() will print both GeneralHeader and MACHeader members). Same for IPHeader - IPHeader.PrintMe() will print GeneralHeader and IPHeader members.

In E language (AOP) it could be easily done by using "is also" to extend the PrintMe() method in MACHeader and IPHeader.

Could you please guide me how to implement it in C++?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: call GeneralHeader::PrintMe from the derived class's PrintMe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to call the `PrintMe` method of the parent class `GeneralHeader` from the `PrintMe` method of `IPHeader` and `MACHeader`. This can be done by prefixing the method call with the parent class. Example:

```
void IPHeader::PrintMe(){
    GeneralHeader::PrintMe(); //Call the super method
    std::cout << "Version: " << Version << std::endl; //Print IPHeader members
}
```

The method of `MACHeader` is analoguous.

If you have polymorphism, i.e., you want to call the `PrintMe` method of a derived class through a pointer or reference of the super class, e.g.:

```
GeneralHeader* h = new IPHeader();
h->PrintMe();
```

then you should declare the method in the `GeneralHeader` class `virtual`. Otherwise, only `PrintMe` of `GeneralHeader` will be called in the above code, even if `h` is actually an `IPHeader`. If you use C++11, you might want to declare the methods in the deriving classes `override` to make sure that they do override `GeneralHeader::PrintMe()`.

Comment: If you don't declare `PrintMe()` as virtual it will fail in polymorphic scenarios.

Comment: @atoMerz it is unclear whether the author has such polymorphic scenarios. If he has, you are right. However, this is not the question here :)

Comment: Right, that might be thee case. But in most situation one would end up using polymorphism, specially when c++ doesn't support RTTI.

Comment: @atoMerz Not really, you may have an application where you don't need it, and it makes little sense to incur in the overhead if you don't need it. But I would at least mention it in the answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Right, I should mention it. As the user seems to be new to C++ I should explain it in more detail. Done.

Comment: @juanchopanza True, thus the use of word `most situations` and not `all situations`.

Comment: @atoMerz But then you would have to provide some statistics to back that claim up :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza Personal experience, if yours is contrary to mine, you can totally ignore me.

Answer (score 2):

This is done by explicitly calling the base class method first:

```
void MACHeader::PrintMe() {
  GeneralHeader::PrintMe();
  std::cout << DestMAC;
}
```

You might also want to consider making the base class' `PrintMe` method virtual. (The explicit call in the derived class will *not* trigger dynamic dispatch)

Howeer, if *all* derivates of `GeneralHeader` *have* to print the general header first, consider the **template method pattern**:

```
class GeneralHeader {
  virtual void PrintDetails() = 0;
public:
  bool Valid;
  void PrintMe() {
    std::cout << "Validity: " << Valid << '\n';
    PrintDetails();
  }
};

struct MACHeader: public GeneralHeader {
  int DestMAC:48;
  void PrintDetails() {
    std::cout << "Dest: " << DestMAC << '\n';
  }
};

struct IPHeader: public GeneralHeader {
  int Version;
  void PrintDetails() {
    std::cout << "Version: " << Version << '\n';
  }
};
```

That way every derived class is forced to implement the `PrintDetails` method, in exchange the ever-returning `GeneralHeader::PrintMe();` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

That's what virtual methods do. Override the parent method in the derived class and call the parent version before doing your own work.

```
class GeneralHeader
{
 public:
 virtual void printMe()
 {
  // print all memebers here
 }
};

class IPHeader : public GeneralHeader
{
 public:
 void printMe()
 {
  GeneralHeader::printMe();//to print parent stuff
  //print new stuff here
 }
};
```

Comment: Or, if you want force the general header:
class GeneralHeader
{
public:
void printMe()
{
//Print header
printMeImpl();
}
protected:
virtual void printMeImpl()=0;
};

Answer (score 0):

though I don't really know what the *is also* is for in E language, do you mean something like the following?

```
GeneralHeader::PrintMe() {
    std::cout<<"valid: "<<Valid<<std::endl;
}

MACHeader::PrintMe() {
    GeneralHeader::PrintMe();
    std::cout<<"dest MAC: ";
    for (int i=0; i<48; ++i)
        std::cout<<i<<":";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
IPHeader::PrintMe() {
   GeneralHeader::PrintMe();
   std::cout<<"Version: "<<version<<std::endl;
}
```

you need to call the function from the mother class `GeneralHeader::PrintMe();` in the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

For example you could do this the following way

```
void MACHeader::PrintMe() 
{ 
   GeneralHeader::PrintMe();
   // ...
}
```

Also you could make the inheritance polymorphic declaring the function as virtual. For example

```
class GeneralHeader {
public:
    bool Valid;
    virtual void PrintMe();
    virtual ~GeneralHeader();
};
```